# Guessing game program using isdigit

Tags: c, random, nested-if

Can someone help me find the error in my code here? I'm totally new to programming and I'm trying to make a simple guessing game that also makes use of the `isdigit()`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

main()
{
    int iRandom = 0;
    int iGuess = 0;
    srand(time(NULL));

    iRandom = rand()%10 + 1;

    printf("\nPlease guess a number between 1 and 10: ");
    scanf("%d", &iGuess);

    if (isdigit(iGuess)){
        if(iGuess == iRandom){
            printf("\nYou guessed the correct number!\n");
        }    
        else{
            printf("\nThat wasn't the correct number!\n");
            printf("\nThe correct number was %d\n", iRandom);
        }
    }
    else{ 
        printf("\nYou did not guess a number.\n");
    }
}
```

The problem is, regardless of whether I enter a number or not, the program returns with "You did not guess a number". Running the gcc compiler doesn't bring up any glaring errors that I can see, either. If my nested `if` statements are messed up, can someone explain why, if `isdigit(iGuess)` is evaluated as true, it would still run the `else` portion?

Comment: consistent indenting of the code (and never use tabs for indenting) makes the code much much easier for us humans to read/understand.  suggest indent 4 spaces after every opening brace '{' and un-indent before every closing brace '}'

Comment: the code is missing the '#include <stdlib.h>' so 1) the compiler will raise a warning about using a undefined function. 2) probably will not work as expected.   Note: the stdlib.h contains the prototypes for many functions, including srand() and rand()

Comment: regarding this line: 'main()' the main() function always returns an 'int' so the correct syntax would be 'int main(void)' however, 'int main()' is allowed. The only other valid syntax is: int main( int argc, char* argv[] )'.   After correcting the main() syntax, then there needs to be a 'return(0);' before the last closing brace of the function

Comment: the code is missing the '#include <time.h> so the compiler will raise a warning about using a undefined function (time()).  The time.h header file contains all the prototypes for the time related functions

Comment: this line: 'printf("\nPlease guess a number between 1 and 10: ");' is asking the user to guess a number 'between' 1 and 10.  I.E. 2...9.  However, the call to rand() is setting 'iRandom' to any value from 1...10  Suggest modifying the user prompt to include 1 and 10

Comment: regarding this call to scanf(): 'scanf("%d", &iGuess);'  always check the returned value (not the parameter value) to assure the input/conversion operation was successful.  (in this case, if the returned value ==1 then successful, otherwise not successful. \

Comment: I appreciate the input and I will fix the things per your suggestion. My biggest issue now is with the 'isdigit()' portion. The code works fine if I remove it, but including it causes the same issue I mentioned before. Unfortunately, I have to use the 'isdigit()' command (it's for a class).

Answer (score 4):

You are using `isdigit()` wrong, it's used to determine whether an ascii value is a digit, you are reading a number, hence you don't need `isdigit()`.

To be usre that a number was actually input, you need to check the return value of `scanf()`, like

```
if (scanf("%d", &iGuess) == 1)
 {
    if(iGuess == iRandom)
        printf("\nYou guessed the correct number!\n");
    else 
     {
        printf("\nThat wasn't the correct number!\n");
        printf("\nThe correct number was %d\n", iRandom);
     }
  }
else
 { 
    printf("\nYou did not INPUT a number.\n");
 }
```

I've seen `scanf()` used in books the wrong way, i.e. ignoring it's return value, as well as other library functions, I suggest reading at least manual pages before starting to use `scanf()`, like [this one](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html) for example.

Back in the days when I was a teenager and wanted to become a programmer, I had a book about using a computer, in it there was a BASIC script which was the first program I read in my whole life, after that my father bought a computer for work it had Windows 95, there was of course MS DOS, and Quick Basic in it, so I started palying with it.

The main source of information was the help, I didn't know that much english, but reading the help I learned about most functions, just by picking a random one and reading, and then by **guessing** what the function probably did from it's name, but even after the **guess** still I read the help.